# Minimum Keystrokes Python Calculator Problem

Tags: python, string, logic

I am having trouble with calculating the minimum number of times you have to press the keyboard to type a certain string. The rules are as follows:

- Each letter you type counts as 1 keystroke
- Activating caps lock counts as 1 keystroke
- Deactivating caps lock counts as 1 keystroke
- Pressing shift counts as 1 keystroke
- You may not hold down shift for more than one letter
- You need to write a function that takes in a string and returns the minimum number (an integer) of keystrokes needed to type that string

I am having some slight issues attempting to code this in Python.
My code so far:

```py
def getAns(string):
    uppercase_count = 0
    keystrokes = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == string[i].upper():
            uppercase_count += 1 
            if uppercase_count == 1:
                keystrokes += 1
        else:
            if uppercase_count > 1:
                keystrokes += 1
            uppercase_count = 0
        keystrokes += 1     
    return keystrokes
```

Test string:

```
"EWlweWXZXxcscSDSDcccsdcfdsFvccDCcDCcdDcGvTvEEdddEEddEdEdAs"
```

My function is returning 79 instead of 78, which it should be. I cannot find any problem in my logic. Can anybody help me?

This is the correct answer code, but I don't get the difference

```
def getAns(self, s):
    if not s:
        return 0
    
    cap = 0
    res = 0
    chars = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
            
    for i,c in enumerate(s):

        if c in chars[cap]:
            res+=1 
        else:
            t = abs(cap - 1)
            
            if i+1 < len(s) and s[i+1] in chars[t]:
                cap = t
                
            res+=2

    return res
```

Comment: It's really hard to follow your code. What is `m`, what is `x` what is `ups` ? Please re-write your code by putting meaningful names (of course if you want to help us with the logic part)

Comment: I think 79 is correct

Comment: And what would happen if string ends to capital ? like `aabCC`

Comment: @Amin Then you wouldn't have to release caps lock. I also put in the solution code, but I can't tell the difference between their logic and mine. ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reduce the input string to the *minimal* substring for which you *still* get a different output, you will identify this substring:

```
"DCcD"
```

For this input, your function will return 7, while the correct code returns 6.

Your function identifies this sequence:

<kbd>Caps ON</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Caps OFF</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> = 7

But... and here it comes... the correct solution identifies this sequence:

<kbd>Caps ON</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> = 6

It takes into account that you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> *while* CAPS-LOCK is on, which will produce a lowercase letter!

Comment: Do you know how to write the function so that it takes that into account?

Comment: But you already have the code for a correct solution?

Comment: Oh wait. For some reason I forgot about that. Sorry